# Version of the Software Installed

Tags: vbscript

I need to find the version of the the software installed in my machine. The code to do that is

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
strComputer = "." 
strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" 
strkey1= "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
strEntry1a = "DisplayName" 
strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName" 
strEntry3 = "VersionMajor" 
strEntry4 = "VersionMinor" 

'to get result in tabular format in html
strResult = "<body><table border=1 cellpadding=5 style=margin-left:50px;><tr><th>Sl No.</th><th>Softwares</th><th>Version</th></tr>"
Dim cnt
cnt=0

'getting the list from win32:_64 bit installed softwares
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & _
"/root/default:StdRegProv") 
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys 

For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
    intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
    strEntry1a, strValue1) 
    If intRet1 <> 0 Then 
        objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
        strEntry1b, strValue1 
    End If 
    objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry3, intValue3 
    objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry4, intValue4 
    If strValue1 <> "" Then 
        'to check the duplicates
        If InStr(strResult,strValue1 & VbCrLf & "</td>")=0 Then
            cnt=cnt+1
            strResult = strResult & "<tr><td>"&cnt & "</td><td>" & strValue1 & VbCrLf & "</td><td>" &intValue3 & "." &intValue4 & "</td></tr>"
        End If
    End If 
Next
```

But the problem is its not giving the full version of the software. 
For example: For vlc 2.7.1, its not printing anything and for others its printing half of it i.e., 8.1 instead of 8.1.61001. How to print the full version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the `DisplayVersion` string instead of the DWORD values `VersionMajor` and `VersionMinor`.

```
objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, "DisplayVersion", version
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you :) But one problem, its not printing the version of few softwares like MATLAB, vlc, 7-zip etc. What can be the reason for it.

Comment: @user387600 The code you posted doesn't check per-user installations, and on 64-bit systems doesn't check the 32-bit registry branch (`strKey1`).